Pull data from trade ogre api with php
https://tradeogre.com/api/v1/markets
I am trying to pull the price of ada to add to my website.
This is what I've tried:
<?php
$content = file_get_contents('https://tradeogre.com/api/v1/markets');

preg_match('#"ADA-USDT":{"initialprice":"(.*)","price":"(.*)"#', $content, $match);
echo $match[2];

?>

I tried and thought it was going to be easy as i have used this code many times!

I have no idea why anyone would attempt to use a regular expression to parse a well-known, well-documented and well-tooled data format such as JSON. Use the right tool for the job - see the duplicate question. Regex is generally the last-resort tool for parsing any kind of data.
